# how should I make this code dry when i need a different action?

Tags: javascript

## Background

I have a method that sets a new active state and also removes the old active state on the previous item. It looks like this

```
if (this.previousActiveItem) {
    const { element, index } = this.previousActiveItem;
    element.classList.remove('active');
    this.items[index - 1].element.classList.remove('active-sibling');
    this.items[index + 1].element.classList.remove('active-sibling');

}
const { element, index } = this.activeItem;
element.classList.add('active');
this.items[index - 1].element.classList.add('active-sibling');
this.items[index + 1].element.classList.add('active-sibling');
```

As you can see it's not DRY since the only difference is that the main target is different and the action `remove` or `add` is different.

## Question

How do I make is code into a function to be reused,

### what I know

I can easily fix the first part with a function that take an element as a variable like this

```
manipulateItem (item) {
    const { element, index } = item;
    element.classList.add('active');
    this.items[index - 1].element.classList.[add || remove]('active-sibling');
    this.items[index + 1].element.classList.[add || remove]('active-sibling');
}
```

But how do i swap out the function call since the arguments are the same. I don't want to bloat it out with a big if statement.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: instead of `add` and `remove` can't you use [`toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods)? that will check if the class exists already and add/remove automatically ...

Comment: So simple, I knew it would be easy to fix. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could access the function as follows as `classList` is an object:

```js
manipulateItem (item, isAdd) {
    const { element, index } = item;
    element.classList[isAdd ? "add" : "remove"]('active');
    this.items[index - 1].element.classList[isAdd ? 'add' : 'remove']('active-sibling');
    this.items[index + 1].element.classList[isAdd ? 'add' : 'remove']('active-sibling');
}
```

```js
this.items = [];
document.querySelectorAll("div.div").forEach((element, index) => {
  this.items.push({
    element: element,
    index: index
  });
});

function manipulateItem(item, isAdd) {
  const {
    element,
    index
  } = item;
  element.classList[isAdd ? "add" : "remove"]('active');
  this.items[index - 1].element.classList[isAdd ? 'add' : 'remove']('active-sibling');
  this.items[index + 1].element.classList[isAdd ? 'add' : 'remove']('active-sibling');
}

function move() {
  var activeElement = document.querySelector("div.active");
  manipulateItem(this.items[1], false);
  manipulateItem(this.items[2], true);
}
```

```css
.active-sibling {
  color: blue;
}

.active {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="div active-sibling">1</div>
<div class="div active">2</div>
<div class="div active-sibling">3</div>
<div class="div">4</div>
<div class="div">5</div>
<button onclick="move();">move</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using `toggle` method of `classList`

```
function manipulateItem (item, add) {
    const { element, index } = item;
    element.classList.toggle('active', add);
    this.items[index - 1].element.classList.toggle('active-sibling', add);
    this.items[index + 1].element.classList.toggle('active-sibling', add);
}

if (this.previousActiveItem) {
    manipulateItem(this.previousActiveItem, false);
}
manipulateItem(this.activeItem, true);
```